# TypeScript 1.5 doesn't produce output

Tags: typescript

Using typescript 1.5 beta.

I have the following problem: if there are errors (from typescript point of view) in .ts files, the output .js files aren't produced and previous output (if any) is erased.

Is it a 1.5 beta limitation or didn't I understand the right way the phrase from typescript official tutorial: "Notice that although there were errors, the greeter.js file is still created. You can use TypeScript even if there are errors in your code"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior changed in 1.4 if you are compiling from Visual Studio.

To change to the old behaviour open the csproj/jsproj in for example notepad and add the following to it

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>false</TypeScriptNoEmitOnError>
</PropertyGroup>
```

It had something to do with the incremental build system where you had for example 5 errors in your ts files which were successfully reported (and it would write JS files to the filesystem). The next build would notice all output files where already uptodate (because of the Timestamps for the JS files and the `.ts` files) and would skip the build and say: "build succeeded" without reporting errors although the code didn't change so there should have been 5 errors.

Hope this helps